# Can't dynamically invoke a method in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

I have a class whose method I want to invoke dynamically. But I am not able to do it. Am I missing something?

```cs
public class P_WATER
    {
        private int[] jDS = new int[20];
        private int n;

        public int[] JDS { get => jDS; set => jDS = value; }
        public int N { get => n; set => n = value; }

        public void P_WATER1()
        {
          //something...
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class Test
{

    P_WATER P_WATERState1 = new P_WATER();
    PLibStateList.Add(P_WATERState1);

    // Try to invoke methods from each objects.
    foreach (object item in StateUtility.PLibStateList)
    {
        Type objType= item.GetType();
        objType.InvokeMember(objType.Name + "1", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, item, null);
    }
}
```

When trying to invoke the method I am getting the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But my assembly is well bound to the project.

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile, but otherwise, the code works.  Post this code in a new project and try to recreate the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same code (with little modifications) in VS2019 (Console App) and worked just fine... weird... check the using statements for ambiguity (just in case):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
```

My full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace cant_dynamically_invoke_a_method_in_c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test.InvokeStuff();
        }
    }

    public class P_WATER
    {
        private int[] jDS = new int[20];
        private int n;

        public int[] JDS { get => jDS; set => jDS = value; }
        public int N { get => n; set => n = value; }

        public void P_WATER1()
        {
            //something...
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void InvokeStuff()
        {
            // Needed to mock this up
            List<P_WATER> PLibStateList = new List<P_WATER>();

            P_WATER P_WATERState1 = new P_WATER();
            PLibStateList.Add(P_WATERState1);

            // Try to invoke methods from each objects.
            foreach (object item in PLibStateList)
            {
                Type objType = item.GetType();
                objType.InvokeMember(objType.Name + "1", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, item, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entered the method successfuly:

[image]

Regards!